# C# Get element in chrome browser WITHOUT Selenium. Just pure C# code

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, element

Is there a easy way to get a element from chrome without using Selenium? Just pure C# code

I was thinking to somehow get the current tab HTML source code and get all the element values that way. Does anybody have any idea how to do this? And it needs to be a already active browser. So i can't use any HTTP request

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a C# interface to the [Chrome DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/). There is such a thing, unsurprisingly called [ChromeDevTools](https://github.com/MasterDevs/ChromeDevTools). The included sample shows you some DOM navigation code.